# I am getting Operation not found: CreateSchedule VENDORPATH/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php at line 296 when i create createSchedule in aws

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to create a scedule for  my php codeignter4 code .
When i am create schedule with sdk php in aws  so I am facing this error Operation not found: CreateSchedule VENDORPATH/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php at line 296

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.